# How is std::auto_ptr initialized with a rvalue?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, c++03, c++98, auto-ptr

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>

std::string foo()
{
    return std::string("yyyyyyyyyyyyy");
}

void bar(std::string& s)
{
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}


std::auto_ptr<std::string> foo1()
{
    bool x = std::rand() % 2;
    if (x) {
        return std::auto_ptr<std::string>(new std::string("eeeeeeeeeeee"));
    } else {
        return std::auto_ptr<std::string>(new std::string("aaaaaaaaaaaaa"));
    }
}


int main()
{
    //bar(foo());
    std::auto_ptr<std::string> a(foo1());    
}
```

The commented line: `bar(foo())` doesn't compile because bar accepts non-const reference and `foo` returns rvalue. But the second line with `std::auto_ptr` compiles. Copy constructor of `std::auto_ptr` also accepts non-const reference. Why then it compiles? I used `std::rand()` in `foo1` to eliminate RVO (Return value optimization).

Comment: [FYI] `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated.  It has been replaced by `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: I know but still need to use old compiler.

Comment: You may want to specify c++98 or C++03 then.  C++ itself includes the current standard which is C++14 right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This apparently works because of a little trick employed to release the internal pointer to the constructing `std::auto_ptr`. **Case 4** from [This Manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr/auto_ptr):

```
template< class Y >
auto_ptr( auto_ptr_ref<Y> m );
```

> 4) Constructs the auto_ptr with the pointer held in the auto_ptr instance referred to by m. p.release() is called for the auto_ptr p that m holds to acquire the ownership of the object.
>   ***auto_ptr_ref is an implementation-defined type that holds a reference to auto_ptr. std::auto_ptr is implicitly convertible to and assignable from this type***. The implementation is allowed to provide the template with a different name or implement equivalent functionality in other ways.

*(emphasis added)*